# What is the key difference between FIDO2 and FIDO UAF?

Tags: authentication, fido, password-less

Since FIDO UAF is now supported by browsers too is there any difference?
Multiple IAM vendors don't support FIDO2 and support UAF only, so curious to know if industry security leaders are not adopting it, what is the real benefit of the updated standard ?